# Cannot read property "0" from undefined. Error Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I´m geting  Cannot read property "0" from undefined. Error on line 16. (  while (colunaDias[emptyCell][0] <= dias) )

It should be a very simple function for google SpreadSheets. I can´t see what I´m doing wrong...

The bizarre thing is that if I don´t use the variable "dias" and use a integer instead. The while function works....

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var leadsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Leads Todas as Categorias, menos outros - Days (5days)");
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("feticaria");

  var cellLeads = leadsSheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  //var cellTarget = targetSheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(valor);

  var colunaDias = leadsSheet.getRange('B:B').getValues();
  var sourceMedium = leadsSheet.getRange('A:A').getValues();
  var emptyCell = 16;
  var dias = 1;

  while (colunaDias[emptyCell][0] != ""){
    while (colunaDias[emptyCell][0] <= dias){
        dias++;
        emptyCell++;
    }


    emptyCell++;

  }

  Logger.log(emptyCell);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only thing that could cause that error is if `emptyCell` is bigger than the `colunaDias` array, i.e. if your sheet is smaller than 16 rows (if the value you show here is correct).

Add this line right before the first `while` :

```
Logger.log('emptyCell = '+emptyCell+'  and colunaDias.length = '+colunaDias.length);
```

I tested a copy of your script and it runs without error except if I define `emptyCell` > 1000 on a 1000 rows Sheet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that `colunaDias[emptyCell]` is undefined.  It passes the first `while` condition, because "undefined" is not equal to "".  If `colunaDias[emptyCell]` is undefined, then either there is something wrong with this line:

```
var colunaDias = leadsSheet.getRange('B:B').getValues();
```

or

```
colunaDias[emptyCell][0]
```

Where "emptyCell" is 16 is the problem.  `getValues()` returns an object of rectangular grid of values.  I would test to see if there is anything in the rectangular grid, by checking [0][0].

```
Logger.log('is there any data? ' + colunaDias[0][0])
```

If there is no data, then the something failed on line:

```
var colunaDias = leadsSheet.getRange('B:B').getValues();
```

If that line is working, then something higher up is wrong.

You should be checking the return type of `getSheetByName` for null.

```
// The code below will log the index of a sheet named "YourSheetName"
var leadsSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("YourSheetName");
if (leadsSheet != null) {
  Logger.log(leadsSheet.getIndex());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this post in from a few years ago, but this was the closest to a problem I am having. I just want to post my answer in case someone else ends up here one day.

For some reason the check variable "dias" is being passed as a string.
That's why replacing it with a number allows the script to run.

```
dias = parseInt(dias);    //use this before the variable needs to be read
```

I cant say why it is passing a string after being ++ but this will fix it